A random urn problem - do the faster duplicating balls always dominate?
There are $N \geq 1$ white balls and $1$ black ball in an (infinitely big) urn. Every turn, a ball is drawn from the urn uniformly at random. If a white ball is drawn, it is put back into the urn along with one more white ball. If a black ball is drawn, it is put back into the urn along with two more black balls.
Write $P_n$ for the ratio of black to white balls in the urn after the $n$'th turn. Is it true that no matter how many white balls we start with, we have $P_n \to \infty$ almost surely?

The answer is yes.
Indeed, let $W_n$ and $B_n$ denote the number of white and black balls at time $n$, $R_n:=W_n/B_n$, and let $E_n$ denote the conditional expectation given $W_1,B_1,\dots,W_n,B_n$. Then
\begin{align}E_n R_{n+1}
&=\frac{W_n+1}{B_n}\frac{W_n}{W_n+B_n}
+\frac{W_n}{B_n+2}\frac{B_n}{W_n+B_n}=C_n R_n, 
\end{align}
where
$$C_n:=\frac{2+B_n+B_n^2+2W_n+B_nW_n}{(B_n+2)(W_n+B_n)}
=1-\frac{B_n-2}{(B_n+2)(W_n+B_n)}.$$
So, letting
$$S_n:=\frac{R_n}{M_n},\quad M_n:=\prod_{k=0}^{n-1} C_k,$$
we see that $(S_n)$ is a nonnegative martingale, which converges almost surely (a.s.) as such.
Note that $W_n+B_n\le2n+c$ for some real $c>0$ and all $n$, and
$$P(\max_n B_n=1)=\frac{N}{N+1}\frac{N+1}{N+2}\cdots=0.$$
Therefore and because $B_{n+1}-B_n\in\{0,2\}$ for all $n$,
for some random integer $\nu$ and all natural $n\ge\nu$ we have $B_n\ge3$ and hence
$$0<C_n\le1-\frac{3-2}{(3+2)(2n+c)}=1-\frac{1}{5(2n+c)}.$$
So, $M_n\to0$ a.s.
Thus, $R_n=M_nS_n\to0$ a.s. $\quad\Box$

Very slick, nice!

Why the downvote? Anything wrong in this answer?

Someone downvoted the original question too :(

@NateRiver : It would be good to have explanations for those downvotes.

@NateRiver I think this is a good question and a good answer. But also I wouldn't lose sleep over every downvote on MO.

@SamHopkins : There may indeed be something wrong with a post, and then it would be good to know. But, yes, losing sleep over that would be too much. :-)

To supplement the calculations in Iosif Pinelis's answer, we can gain a more qualitative understanding by rephrasing the problem slightly:
Instead of a discrete-time process where we pick balls one by one, let time be continuous, and let each ball separately pick a random time to split into either 2 or 3 balls of the same color. The balls that result from each split then again pick random times to split themselves.
If all balls pick their lifetime independently from a common exponential distribution, then whenever we look at the urn, every ball in it will be equally likely to be the next ball to split. So given a concrete outcome of the continuous process, if we reparameterize the time to make the splits happen at times 1, 2, 3, … then we'll see the various infinite (discrete) histories appear with the same distribution as the original pick-one-at-a-time experiment. So this reformulation is indeed just a reformulation.
However, in the continuous-time formulation, it is immediate that the growth history of the number of black balls and of the number of white balls are completely independent of each other. The expected number of black balls will grow exponentially (*), as will the expected number of white balls — but the number of black balls grows twice as fast (since each split event increases the number by 2 instead of by 1), so eventually the black count should overtake the white count, beating any given ratio.
That doesn't quite prove that $P_n$ converges to $\infty$ a.s. However, a history where $P_n$ doesn't so converge would be a history where the black balls tend to live longer than the white balls and keep doing that forever, which at least intuitively ought to be a probability-zero event.
(*) At first I thought this would be just an approximation until there are "many" balls of the same color, but it turns out that the exponential growth of the expectation is exact thanks to linearity, even when the numbers are small.

The rephrasing can be described more abstractly as making the original discrete-time Markov chain into a continuous-time Markov chain by assigning to each state (identified by the number of white and black balls in the urn) a holding time inversely proportional to the total number of balls. It then turns out that the resulting continuous-time chain factors as a product of separate white and black chains which are each pure birth processes.
In this view, the misgiving Christian Remling puts forth in a comment can be understood as being about the risk that the CTMC might explode, i.e. make infinitely many transitions in finite time. If that can happen with nonzero probability, the whole rewriting is meaningless. So we need some additional reasoning to convince ourselves that the CTMC is not explosive.
There are some easy standard sufficient conditions for non-explosiveness, which are unfortunately not satisfied here. Instead I will just wave my hands and claim that it follows from each of the white and black chains being pretty well-behaved (and in fact isomorphic to the example in the above Wikipedia article) when analyzed in isolation. This would not be the case if (as in Christian Remling's comment) we modify the rules for the original game such that each white draw is replaced by increasing numbers of new white balls.

Nice idea! To upgrade the expected growth bounds to a.s. convergence I think is where martingale theory becomes necessary. The key is that the conditional expectations given earlier times exhibit the same pattern of exponential growth too.

Something makes me nervous about your claim that one can consider white and black balls separately, with no interaction between them. One could change the rules slightly in the original set-up, for example replace the first white ball drawn by two white balls, the second one by $4$, the third one by $8$ etc. In that case, there is a positive probability of never drawing the black ball, but your model seems to suggest that the black balls happily multiply on their own anyway.

@ChristianRemling: Good point -- there's a hidden step in my argument where we need to make sure that my new continuous time coordinate is unbounded. If we apply my transformation to your increasing-profits rule, the expected number of white balls would be increasing superexponentially and escape to infinity in a finite time, at which point the lone black ball might not have gotten around to multiplying yet. In order to be sure this doesn't happen in the original case, we'd need to work out the differential equation for how the expectations grow, and see they are indeed only exponential.
